# I need to store the value to variable with int type but int is not enough?

Tags: java, int, size

I had Started a new project for school Called BasesConvertor with Java in android app

So My problem is: 
- to convert Base 10 To an other bases I need to store the value to variable with int type but int is not enough
Max int size is : 2,147,483,647

- and small value of Hexadecimal equal a big value of decimal 
  ex : FFFFFFFFFFFF(16) = 281 474 976 710 655(10)

Comment: Use a `long` then?

Comment: I can do mathematics operation with Long type lik Long Num = 123456789.../2 Division or modulo ?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `72057594037927702` is too long for `int` **and** `long`. You will have to use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("72057594037927702");
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to use mathematical operations such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, etc. you will  need to use the predefined methods in the `BigInteger` class:

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("72057594037927702");
System.out.println(i);
//  Add five
i = i.add(new BigInteger("5"));
System.out.println(i);
// Take tree
i = i.subtract(new BigInteger("3"));
System.out.println(i);
// Four times
i = i.multiply(new BigInteger("5"));
System.out.println(i);
// Divided among 2
i = i.divide(new BigInteger("2"));
System.out.println(i);

/*
 * Output:
 *      72057594037927702
 *      72057594037927707
 *      72057594037927704
 *      360287970189638520
 *      180143985094819260
 */
```

Comment: BigInteger Support mathematics operation ? Lik division or modulo

Answer (score -1):

you can try storing the value in a different data type, say double would do and check out this chart it might help

http://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/java-primitive-data-types.php

This chart has all the data types and their limits

Comment: Ok thanks Long or double are the best option But if i can do mathematics operation with this type lik Long number /2 our Lon Number % 2 ...

Comment: you can do  mathematical operations using any data type

Comment: You cannot represent numbers in `double` with more than 15 digits precision.  `double` is not an option for the OP, only `BigDecimal` will work in this case.